# Android O Developer preview is not available in SDK

Tags: android, android-studio, android-8.0-oreo

As we know recently developer preview of `Android-O` has been released. I am trying to update my `SDK` with it but somehow it is not showing me any options.

It is just showing me until Android 7.1.1(Nougat)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get the canary version of Android Studio 2.4 to begin using the Android O SDK. Looks like it's temporary limitation. More details here:
https://developer.android.com/preview/migration.html#ptb

Comment: oh yes, seems its just available with Android Studio 2.4 canary channel. Thanks

Comment: I am using eclipse and SDK manager. Preview is not listing in my SDK manager. Is this anything to with the IDE I am using. Is it because I am using Eclipse Android 7.0.2 is not listing.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to get android studio 2.4 canary as mentioned in https://android-developers.googleblog.com/

**The latest canary version of Android Studio 2.4 includes new features to help you get started with Android O. You can download and set up the O preview SDK from inside Android Studio**

Here is the official link to get `AS 2.4` https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Install Android Studio 2.4 canary, this is mandatory for using android O sdk.

More details follow this link
https://developer.android.com/preview/migration.html#ptb

Answer (score 1):

[image: Android 8.0 package details]Android 8.0 is now available in Android Studio 2.3.3

It will be in updates which are shown when you start your android studio or access it from the menu bar.

Also, it is a problem that many developers are facing that many developers are facing, is that it's showing partially installed even when you have all the packages in API 26 downloaded.In spite of that, the SDK will work.

Comment: Is the information clear enough or should I add some more details kindly let me know and I will add it.I am uploading a picture of the partially installed API too.